# Merging Data from Duplicate Client Records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access database that contains two tables:  client and eventAttendance.  Client stores data when a client registers for the first time.  EventAttendance contains the Id of the event, clientID, and the date the client attended the event.  Duplicate records exist in the client table.  Many clients have multiple clientIDs.  These clientIDs are used to register for events so the same individual client may have registered for eight different events with eight different clientIDs.

I have identified the clients in the client table with multiple clientIDs but I am uncertain on how to now merge the records in the eventAttendance table.  Can anyone recommend how I should handle this situation?

**Table Client**

```
ClientID  Name   Email
1         Jack   Jack@gmail.com
2         Jill   Jill@gmail.com
3         Jack   Jack@gmail.com
```

**Table EventAttendance**

```
EventID   ClientID   AttendanceDate
1         1          6/1/2000
1         3          6/1/2001
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'm a few years removed from MS-Access, so I'll try to keep my SQL Generic. I'd consider this pseudo code whose purpose is to communicate the steps to accomplish your goal of removing dupe clients.

**Step 1, Update the Client ID's in the Event Attendance Table to match the Minimum ClientID of Duplicated Client Records**

The only trick here is grouping all clients, and using the `MIN` aggregate function to determine the lowest-ClientID per Client.

```
UPDATE EventAttendance set ClientID = C2.ClientID
FROM
  EventAttendance as E
  INNER JOIN Clients as C1 on C1.ClientID = E.ClientID
  -- Re-Join with Clients to obtain the Minimum ClientID per Client
  INNER JOIN (Select Min(ClientID) as MinClientID FROM Clients GROUP BY ClientName) as C2 on C1.ClientName = C2.ClientName
```

**Step 2, Delete all but the first Client Record for each Client**

Step 1 cleared out any references to dupe clients, so we are free to delete the dupes.

```
DELETE FROM Clients 
WHERE ClientID not in 
  -- If the current record's ClientID is not in the following, then it is a dupe that is OK to be deleted
  (Select Min(ClientID) as MinClientID FROM Clients GROUP BY ClientName)
```

**Notes**

- The above assumes ClientName is unique per person. If this is not a good field, you might try email address, or a concatenation of multiple records to establish uniqueness.
- After fixing the data, [add a uniqueness constraint](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-constraint-adp-HP003088257.aspx) to the Client Name or Email Address (preferred) columns

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like inconsistent data problem.

You'd need to have a unique id for one client that you can map in EventAttendance table to make it 1-m relationship. Since you've identified similarity between duplicate records in clientid, creating unique id won't be a problem. Create a new column in client table and assign a unique number to each duplicate client records for same client. Now you need to write an update statement where you can update EventAttendance table clientId column with new id. This is one way of doing it.

once you've updated, you can remove duplicate records of clients except the first one and assign it its unique ID and drop the Unique ID column that was created to identify one client and referring it in EventAttendance Table as foreign key.

But i'd prefer to restrict clients creating duplicate ids by their email address.

Comment: I don't know that the assumption that email address is a candidate key is correct. I've got a project that is exactly this kind of situation, i.e., with conference registration data, and many companies provide a single email address for multiple registrants. And an individual person may register with a different email address for different events. But, of course, it depends on the business rules in the particular application.